Конвертация PNG в BTX на python
Столкнулся с расширением BTX, которое сделано из файлов PNG.
Хотелось бы спросить у знающих людей, как мне конвертировать через Python картинку PNG в BTX и обратно?
На GitHub-е есть код по запросу 'png to btx', но там бот телеграм, хотелось бы найти просто утилиту..

https://gist.github.com/xyzz/fbb344f4c2e9bba1ad12215a72db5035
